# WebClient underlying connection closed / SSL/TLS enabled, but only working on local machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a small program that gets some data from a different server. This program runs as a planned task on Windows Server. Last week the program didn't work because the WebClient gets an error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Unexpected error during
> transmission.

So I changed the code to:

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        string data = wc.DownloadString(URI);
```

This works fine for me on my local machine. But on the server, I am getting the error

> The request was aborted: A protected SSL/TLS channel could not be
> created.

Has someone an idea what I have to configure, that this program is running again?

Comment: Are you sure the server you connect accept those secure protocols?

Comment: Setting the SecurityProtocol only does one does one protocol.  So after Tls11 fails you need second request trying Tls12.  Most servers are current stopping the use of Tls11.  there are lots of reasons code could work on one machine and not another.  It appears code has been working for a long time and just recently stopped working.  You may of been using tls11 and now the server stopped using tsl11 but you local machine is still using tls11.